# Transport.send() takes 15 minutes to complete

Tags: java, android, sockets, jakarta-mail

Well i know this question has been asked earlier here. I have seen all the solutions and inputs provided. But i cannot fix this.
Earlier the same code was working fine, Now every send call take around 15 -20 mins to actually gets executed.

I think I'm passing the right arguments. Can someone tell me why it takes so much time?

Here is the LOG file:

```
C:\Users\Digital Jalebi - uno\Desktop\naval.txt
Fetched from filenavaljosh@gmail.com;nn.jpg
Email:navaljosh@gmail.comimage:C:\Users\Digital Jalebi - uno\Desktop\naval\nn.jpg
Filling details
send to mail auth file
navaljosh@gmail.com
lenth receipient2
Filling final msg
1
2
3
4
< here it waits for 15 minutes - on transport.send() and then gets executed>
5
From: Navaljoshi <navaljosh@gmail.com>
Reply-to: Navaljoshi <navaljosh@gmail.com>
To: jabongnbajam@gmail.com
Subject: Fwd: EXTRA 32% Off on 2Lac+ Styles
Sent: Thu Oct 08 11:18:14 IST 2015
javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart@72e1bc00
message forwarded ....
Sucessfully Sent mail to All Users
Fetched from filenull
sleeping1
woke1
Fetched from filenull
sleeping1
```

Code:

```
    public class SendMailUsingAuthentication {

        private String HOST_NAME = "gmail-smtp.l.google.com";
        String messageBody;

        @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
        public void postMail(String recipients[], String subject, String message,
                String from, String emailPassword, String files) throws MessagingException {
            boolean debug = false;
            java.security.Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
     try{
            //Set the host smtp address
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST_NAME);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");


            Authenticator authenticator = new SMTPAuthenticator(from,emailPassword);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);

            session.setDebug(debug);

            // create a message
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            // set the from and to address
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);
            System.out.println(addressFrom);

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            System.out.println("lenth receipient"+recipients.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i],false);
            }

            System.out.println("Filling final msg");
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            // Setting the Subject and Content Type
            msg.setSubject(subject);
           // msg.setContent(message, "text/html");

            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(message);
            System.out.println("1");

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            //add the message body to the mime message
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            System.out.println("2");

            // add any file attachments to the message
            addAtachments(files, multipart);
            System.out.println("3");
            //Put all message parts in the message
            msg.setContent(multipart);
            System.out.println("4");
            Transport.send(msg);
     }
     catch(MessagingException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("in catch mesg exp");
     }
            System.out.println("5");
            ForwardMail frw = new ForwardMail();
            frw.emaiTo = recipients[0];
            ForwardMail.sent();
            System.out.println("Sucessfully Sent mail to All Users");
        }

        protected void addAtachments(String attachments, Multipart multipart)
                throws MessagingException, AddressException {
           // for (int i = 0; i <= attachments.length - 1; i++) {
                String filename = attachments;
                MimeBodyPart attachmentBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                //use a JAF FileDataSource as it does MIME type detection
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
                attachmentBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                attachmentBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
                //add the attachment
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentBodyPart);
          //  }
        }
```

Comment: 'Going in infinite loop' != 'takes around 15-20 minutes to actually get executed'. Which is it?

Comment: @Asmi Why did your edit remove the log? Don't vandalize posts here.

Comment: Well it goes in  a loop and actually completes in  - minutes.

Comment: Don't post guesswork as fact. You don't know what it does internally. If it completes, it can't be in an infinite loop. Surely this is obvious? The salient thing is that it takes a long time to complete.

Comment: Well thats the question, why it takes that much of time, initially it dosent??

Comment: That's my point. Posting with an irrelevant title and irrelevant speculation about what it is doing inside doesn't help your cause.

Comment: If i know whats going inside , i would not have asked, and its nbot irrelevant . Even you don't know whats the reason.

Comment: If you don't know what was going on inside you shouldn't post a question and title that imply that you do. The point is that you should ask about the actual problem you're experiencing, and title your question accordingly. Surely this also is obvious? Whether I know the answer isn't relevant to that. Whether you get the right people to read your question on the other hand is extremely relevant. I shouldn't have had to fix your question for you.

Comment: Note: This title was edited by one of the moderators.I tried to be very clear with my title.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up your program by fixing all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), and then following this [example for using Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

If that doesn't solve your problem (and I don't think it will), turn on [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug); by watching where the debug output pauses, you might be able to determine what it's doing when it slows down.  Most likely the problem is a name service problem (looking up the host name for Gmail), or a firewall or anti-virus program interposing on your connection attempt.

Answer (score -1):

You are setting up mail.smtp.host twice.

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); 
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST_NAME);

Test with one host only and see.

also you can add a property to see if the mail server connection has issues.

properties.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "15000");

P

Comment: No success, Tried both your suggestions. Initially it worked fine.. still if i wait for 15 mins it will.

Comment: mail.smtp.connectiontimeout property value is in milliseconds, so it is 15 seconds. what do you mean Initially it worked fine. Which javamail jar file are you using.